# how to set full height of the content part

Tags: html, css

i am creating one responsive site and divide page in three part

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

the height of the "header" and "footer" is 30px now how to set the height of the "content" by which i can display content in full page with the less content.

that means if we open this page in ipad then it's height is more then desktop so footer display between the screen the how i can put it at bottom at any screen.

i don't want to set position:fixed; because it always set it bottom so problem when the content is more then the screen

Comment: Take a look at media queries. They will handle all the changes you will want to make depending on what device the page is being viewed on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.header, .footer{
    height:30px;
    background: #000000;
}

.content {
    background : #ff0000;
    min-height: calc(100% - 60px);
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/VsAUV/3/

If you want to support older browsers do it this way: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: You have used height instead of min-height in the demo. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VsAUV/2/) is the updated code.

Comment: by using this i got perfect output but in table the inner div of the "content" div not work properly

that means in "content" to child class "menu","data" they not increase them height only parent div increase